# Changing multiple select query into CTE query

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I want to change this particular simple select query into CTE in order to optimize it, as this simple three select query taking 4 mins and so, I want to reduce the execution time of it by converting it into CTE query.

```
select sum(AMOUNT) usd from data where status IN ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') and date between '01-SEP-18' and '30-NOV-18' 
UNION 
select sum(AMOUNT) usd from data where status IN ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') and date between '01-NOV-18' and '31-JAN-19' 
UNION 
select sum(AMOUNT) usd from data where status IN ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') and date between '01-FEB-19' and '30-APR-19' 
ORDER BY usd DESC ;
```

The expected result should be one column showing the result of the three queries, which is the sum as usd of the amount in this query.

Example:

```
USD
100 (timeline 1)
200 (timeline 2)
300 (timeline 3)
```

The one I tried:
Can you conver this CTE query with sum instead of count.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2019-01-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30' THEN 1 END) AS cnt2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 1 END) AS cnt3
    FROM data
    WHERE status IN ('ACCEPTED', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED')
)

SELECT cnt1 FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cnt2 FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT cnt3 FROM cte;
```

Comment: Do you really intend for the timelines to overlap?

Comment: Here I am running the same select query with different timelines. Because I need the data for three different quarters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you don't want the timelines to overlap, so:

```
select (case when date between '01-SEP-18' and '30-NOV-18' then 'timeline1'
             when date between '01-DEC-18' and '31-JAN-19' then 'timeline2'
             when date between '01-FEB-19' and '30-APR-19' then 'timeline3'
        end), sum(AMOUNT) as usd
from data
where status IN ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') and 
     date between '01-SEP-18' and '30-APR-19'
group by (case when date between '01-SEP-18' and '30-NOV-18' then 'timeline1'
               when date between '01-DEC-18' and '31-JAN-19' then 'timeline2'
               when date between '01-FEB-19' and '30-APR-19' then 'timeline3'
        end)
order   by usd desc;
```

If you do, separate columns are probably simpler:

```
select sum(case when date >= date '2018-09-01' and date < date '2018-12-01' then amount end) as usd_timeline1,
       sum(case when date >= date '2018-11-01' and date < date '2019-02-01' then amount end) as usd_timeline2
       sum(case when date >= date '2019-02-01' and date '2019-05-01' then amount end) as usd_timeline3
from data
where status IN ('ACCEPTED','REJECTED','CANCELLED') and 
      date >= date '2018-09-01' and date < date '2019-05-01'
order by usd desc;
```

Note that this uses date constants using the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format and the `date` keyword.

Comment: I have edited the question to new can you look at it an convert it into using aggregate function because I don't want the count but just the sum, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: and also you forgot to use the WITH clause

Comment: I have made some modifications to your query and it starts working, thanks or your help gordon